# Python lock file on file change

Tags: python, file

There are some modules for monitoring file or directories in Python such as watchdog or inotify.

I would like to do the following:

1. File is being modified
2. Catch a file change event using Python and lock the un-modified file
3. Do something with the un-modified file
4. Release the file
5. Let the file to be modified

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Sure.  Do a little research, show us what you've tried and any errors that you haven't been able to figure out. We'd be happy to help at that point.

Answer (score 0):

[inotify](https://github.com/dsoprea/PyInotify/blob/78670d829ba363dcdde814513990e31e0e8eb7b7/inotify/constants.py) has various events, which allow you to react on:

```
IN_ACCESS        = 0x00000001
IN_MODIFY        = 0x00000002
IN_ATTRIB        = 0x00000004
IN_CLOSE_WRITE   = 0x00000008
IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE = 0x00000010
IN_OPEN          = 0x00000020
IN_MOVED_FROM    = 0x00000040
IN_MOVED_TO      = 0x00000080
IN_CREATE        = 0x00000100
IN_DELETE        = 0x00000200
IN_DELETE_SELF   = 0x00000400
IN_MOVE_SELF     = 0x00000800
```

So in theory it might be possible.